# I'm using power automate to query an access database and I want to know how to return the query headers to my output

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm directly querying a local access database using power automate desktop.  I'm performing an sql query directly into access by way of an open sql connection in power automate rather than pulling data from a stored results table. When I write the query results to an excel file in the same flow I get my results but not the result column headers.  I've looked through most of the answers provided here and they all suggest MySQL, SQL server, or other solutions that I simply don't have.

My current query looks like:

```
SELECT table1.uid, table2.[job.title], table1.[start.date], 
table1.[end.date], table2.company, table1.role, table2.active
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table.2 ON table1.uid=tables.uid
```

And so when I run the query my column headers are UID, job title, start date, end date, company, role, active.

I'd like those headers generated by the query to carry over to the Excel sheet so I don't have to manually insert them.

In short can I write an sql query that directly connects to access through an open sql connection in power automate and have it return the data and the data column headers?

Comment: Query shows `=tables.uid`, should that be `=table2.uid`?

Comment: also make sure to replace table.2 with table2